# Label outside the tableView in the same view Controller does not scroll along with table View

Tags: objective-c

I want a label and a table view inside the same View Controller. I have added the objects in the storyboard but the problem is that the label is not scrolling along with the table view. I tried putting the label and the table view in a scroll view but this also doesn't help as the scroll view doesn't scroll.

Can anyone please tell me how can I scroll the label along with the table view.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Descriptions are nice, but code is nicer.

Comment: put the label in tableview header

Comment: scrollview and tableview both has its scrolling. when you can scroll in that viewcontroller, originally tableview is scrolled not scrollview. so, set FALSE in "scrolling enabled" property of uitableview and after check.

Comment: check first, have u properly set '@property' and '@synthesize' ?? and also properly connect UILabel to file's owner ??

Comment: if possible use tableHeaderView property.

Comment: Thanks for your advices . I have added the label in the tableview header and it looks great .